# How Read pdf file in android?

Tags: android

I'm not success for Pdf Reader in android.

Comment: did u Google for it ? is it so difficult ?

Comment: see moderator has closed question

Answer (score 2):

You can use Adobe Reader for Android 
http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html

Comment: Thanks for Link. But i have to develop that Reader in my apllication.

Comment: how did you done that? please post the links on here so every body can use it

Answer (score 1):

iText is an opensource framework for reading pdf, which written in java language, that maybe used in android,but i'm not sure of that